# How to change font size in scanpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scanpy

I am generating dotplots using `scanpy` and unable to change the font size. Is there a way to do so?

For example, how would I edit this line of code?

`sc.pl.dotplot(df,  ["gene"], 'CellType', dendrogram=True,  save = name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, scanpy just uses matplotlib under the hood, so there are several options:

You can set the fontsize globally:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 'large'})
```

You can update specifically only the fontsize of (all) axis labels:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'axes.labelsize' : 'large'}) 
plt.rcParams.update({'axes.xtick.labelsize' : 'large'})   
plt.rcParams.update({'axes.ytick.labelsize' : 'large'})
```

Finally, if you have a handle of the axis, you can change the fontsize of labels by traversing the axis attributes:

```
dp_object = sc.pl.dotplot(df,  ["gene"], 'CellType', dendrogram=True,  save = name)
axes_dict = dp_object.get_axes()
# figure out which axis you want by printing the axes_dict
# print(axes_dict)
ax = axes_dict[...]
ax.xaxis.label.set_fontsize(22)
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize('large')
```

Comment: I think you meant plt.rcParams.update? The second block of code doesn't compile. The third block generates larger fonts in a separate plot, unfortunately.

Comment: Good catch; I fixed the typo. And yeah, I overlooked that you were plotting more than one component due to the `groupby`. In that case, you can access the axes using the `dotplot_object.get_axes` method (shown in updated answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_axes'` running dp_object.get_axes(). Not sure how to resolve, have definitely spent a non-trivial amount of time trying to figure this out...

Comment: Maybe a problem with your version? I am pretty sure that feature worked at some time (see last example in the [docs](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/scanpy.pl.dotplot.html).

Comment: I figured it out, thanks so much! Turns out you have to set return_fig=True!

Comment: and use `rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 20.0` to set the size for the figure title

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do this directly using scanpy with the following:

`sc.set_figure_params(scanpy=True, fontsize=14)`

However, I am still unsure how to change the y axis specifically...